# If more than one user is on a twist phase do they each draw their own phase?

Tags: phase-10

In Phase 10 Twist there are only 10 twist phases.  If everybody drew their own twist phase then we'd run out really quickly.

So, if more than one person is on a twist phase at a time, do they all play the same twist phase or do they each draw their own phase and we just recycle the cards when we run out?

Comment: @ire_and_curses Thanks for the retag. Wish there was a more elegant way of requesting that at low rep levels.

Comment: No problem. One option is to flag if you don't want to make the request so prominent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading the rules we decided that it was best to have each player on a twist phase draw their own card and we'd just recycle them when we ran out.

The reason for this being, players aren't obligated to show other players their twist phase.  If all players drew the same twist phase then this sort of secretive strategy part of the game would be lost.

We also doubled the number of twist cards we have since somebody spilled beer on our first board and we had to get a new one.  The cards weren't ruined though so now we just double them up and have to recycle them less often.